# How to display image on lock screen for the pass

Tags: ios6, passbook

On lock screen, I can show text. What about image ? How to show it ? I try "`relevantText": "CamMob\uD83D\uDE1C\uD83D\uDE4B`", but only text displays!

Comment: In this case, what characters show? Just CamMob or something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot display regular images, but you can encode emoji characters into any of the pass fields and Passbook will display them.

To include emoji, you need to find the utf-8 representation of the character(s) that you want.

You can get this by right clicking the character in the character viewer and copying the Character info.

[image: Character Viewer]
[image: Character Viewer Emoji]

Another quick and easy way would be with a PHP file containing the following:

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array("relevantText" => ""));
```

*Note: the above will only look cool in Safari on a Mac! Don't bitch if you see lots of ?????*

Just make sure that your php file is saved with utf-8 encoding.

Comment: I need to add this : header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
 ?

Comment: and should I put '<?php
echo json_encode(array("relevantText" => "")); ' in index.php ?

Comment: No,just a separate file - this code will give you the unicode representation of the emoji characters.

Comment: now i can see it by using :       "relevantText": "CamMob\ud83d\ude1c\ud83d\ude4b"

Comment: Sorry, I meant what changed in your code? Other than the lowercase which should not matter, your code looks the same.